# Отделить id от url

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

В регулярках вообще не соображаю даже самое элементарное не могу сделать.Помогите отделить id от url есть список с адресами страниц где id могут быть либо цифры либо никнеймы.

```
["https://vk.com/phrodionov" , "https://vk.com/id4308" ,  "https://vk.com/id4924"]
```

Comment: Почему бы не пройтись по массиву и не заменить строку, убрав "https://vk.com/"?

Comment: @SwaD А как убрать vk.com/id

Comment: что тут отделять-то? url - ``https://vk.com/``, id - все, что после этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно непонятно зачем тут регулярка, но если хочется регулярку, то вот:
`(?<=vk\.com\/).*`

- `.*` — забираем любые символы, т.е. id'шники с цифрами и текстовые.
  Можно использовать `.+` quantifier, тогда ссылки без id, т.е. просто "vk.com/" в результат не пойдут
- `(?<=vk\.com\/)` — positive lookbehind, т.е. регулярка сработает только если перед тем что мы хотим найти стоит "vk.com/"
- `\.` и `\/` — в ссылку vk.com/ необходимо добавить escape character, т.е. обратный слеш, т.к. точка и прямой слеш являются частью синтаксиса регулярных выражений

### Update

Из комментариев:

> Она все ровно выдает с id

```python
pattern=r'(?<=vk\.com\/)((?:id)(\d+)|.*)'
arr = ["https://vk.com/phrodionov" , "https://vk.com/id4308" ,  "https://vk.com/id4924"]
for x in arr:
    print([x for x in re.search(pattern, x).groups() if x != None][-1])
```

###### Вывод:

```
phrodionov
4308
4924
```

Comment: Можно переделать без id чтобы просто цифры были 4308  4924

Comment: По вопросу не понятно надо убирать id или нет. Но, хмм, а это интереснее. `(?<=vk\.com\/)((id)(\d+)|.*)`

Comment: Да нужно про цифры.

Comment: Серьезно это регулярными не сделать?

Comment: @teamarden я же выше в комментарии дал регулярку

Comment: Она все ровно выдает с id

Comment: @teamarden почитай как группы работают